# Creating a StoryMap app using the rallycardboard

Tags: rally

I'd like to put together a StoryMap app using Initiative (second level) portfolio items as the backbone (columns).  To do this the app needs to query for all the second level portfolio items, and then use each PI as a column header in the rallycardboard.

I've gotten the cardboard to display the column headers correctly, but I have not been able to get it to display the cards, which should be the first level of portfolio items (PortfolioItem/Feature).

Here is my code so far:

```
launch: function() {
    this._getInitiativeStore();
},

_getInitiativeStore: function() {
    this.initiativeStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
        model: 'PortfolioItem/Initiative',
        fetch: ['Name', 'Children'],
        autoLoad: true,
        listeners: {
            load: this._createCardBoard,
            scope: this
        }
    });
},

_createCardBoard: function(store, records) {
    var initiativeColumns = [];

    Ext.each(records, function(record) {
        initiativeColumns.push({
            xtype: 'rallycardboardcolumn',
            columnHeaderConfig: {
                xtype: 'rallycardboardcolumnheader',
                fieldToDisplay: 'Name',
                record: record,
            },
            cardConfig: {
                xtype: 'rallycard',
                record: 'PortfolioItem/Feature'
            },
            fields: ['Name', 'Parent'],
            valueField: 'Parent',
            value: record.get('_ref') // BUG FIXED HERE.  Was: record.get('Parent')
        });
    }, this);

    var cardBoardConfig = {
            xtype: 'rallycardboard',
            types: ['PortfolioItem/Feature'],
            columns: initiativeColumns,
            attribute: 'Parent',
        };
    var cardBoard = this.add(cardBoardConfig);

    console.log('cardboard', cardBoard);
}
```

I realize I am using this perhaps a bit differently than the authors have planned for, but I'm willing to extend the rallycardboard and rallycolumnheader objects with Ext.define if that's what it takes.  I'm starting to look at the Rally source code but its slow going so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem by using Ext.define() to override the cardboardcolumn getStoreFilter function to print out its filter value.  Probably for somebody good with a browser debugger that would not have been necessary, but I'm not and it pinpointed the problem right away:  The "value" field of the initiativeColumn configs should have been record.get('_ref'), not record.get('Parent').  I'll edit the code above so it works.

Now the basic board works great as a story map with portfolio items!  Next step is to see if I can incorporate the concept of releases into the map.

Also, I think I found a bug in the 'rallycardboard' constructor-- if I pass it a context reference like: context: { project: 'project/XXX'} where XXX is an OID, it crashes.  Instead I need to instantiate a context object and pass that.  But that's inconsistent from other items like the wsapi store.  Workaround is easy, but it is a bit annoying.